# BigQuery - Inner Join Each results size

Tags: join, inner-join, google-bigquery

I'm trying to join two tables in BigQuery:

```sql
SELECT MU.C FROM MU
INNER JOIN EACH MM
ON  MU.C = MM.P_C;
```

MU has approximately 7 million records and MM has 45 mil records.
I want to find the records in MU that match MM.

I cannot use INNER JOIN due to the large size. However INNER JOIN EACH is giving me a result of 239 mil records.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you give more details? the problem is that you are expecting less than 7 million records, but doing a COUNT(*) on the join gives you 239 million records instead?

Comment: I'm running the exact query above. The result table has 239mil rows. Yes, I'm expecting 7mil or fewer records.

Comment: can you describe both tables? I have that kind of problems before - when I was doing a JOIN on less fields that I should had. In my case, I was doing a JOIN ON a.x=b.x, but I should have been doing a JOIN ON a.x=b.x AND a.y=b.y AND a.z=b.z. It all depends on how the data is structured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semantics of join are that when the same key matches multiple times on each side of the join, you'll get the cross-product of the join keys. In the worst case, you could end up with N * M rows, where N is the number of tables on the left and M is the number of tables on the right.

Let's say you have the following tables

```
T1: 
[{a: 1, b: "foo"},
 {a: 1, b: "bar"},
 {a: 2, b: "baz")]

T2: 
[{x: 1, y: "one"},
 {x: 1, y: "two",
 {x: 2, y: "three"}]
```

And you join them together via the statement

```
SELECT t1.a as a, t1.b as b, t2.y s y 
FROM T1 JOIN T2 on t1.a = t2.y
```

You'll get more rows than you started out with --

```
[{a: 1, b: "foo", y: "one"},
 {a: 1, b: "foo", y: "two"},
 {a: 1, b: "bar", y: "one"},
 {a: 1, b: "bar", y: "two"},
 {a: 2, b: "baz", y: "three")]
```

You should check to make sure that the keys your joining are unique on at least one of the sides. That is you should make sure that one of the following doesn't return any values

```
SELECT C, count(*) as cnt FROM MU GROUP EACH BY C HAVING cnt > 1
SELECT C, conut(*) as cnt FROM MM GROUP EACH BY C HAVING cnt > 1
```

An alternative is to run the group by on one of your tables before the join in a subequery. E.g.

```
SELECT MU.C 
FROM MU 
INNER JOIN EACH (SELECT C FROM MM GROUP EACH BY C) 
ON MU.C = MM.P_C;
```

Comment: So I tried this:
Created a table NEW_MU using: 
SELECT C FROM MU GROUP EACH BY C 

And tried 
SELECT NEW_MU.C FROM NEW_MU
INNER JOIN EACH MM
ON NEW_MU.C = MM.C

This too results returns more rows than NEW_MU or MM. I also tried LEFT, LEFT OUTER, JOIN to get similar results. 

All I want is to get C's from NEW_MU that are also in MM.

Comment: It sounds like the MM table may have duplicate values as well. A default join will take all of the rows on the left table (the table mentioned in the FROM clause) and pair them with all matching rows in the right table (the JOIN clause). Your best bet may be to switch left and right (e.g. SELECT NEW_MU.C FROM MM INNER JOIN EACH NEW_MU ON NEW_MU.C = MM)

Comment: The other option you have is to do a SEMIJOIN. That is, 'SELECT C FROM NEW_MU WHERE C in (SELECT C FROM MM)'

Comment: MM table does have duplicates. However both options did not work. 

First option still gives a much bigger result. 
Option two returns table is too large.

Comment: Hi Febian. We need to know more about your tables/data. Can you describe the table for us? Or if you can share the dataset with me, I can take a look into it.